# Scan a document without saving

Tags: windows-xp, fax

On Windows 7, Windows Fax and Scan wizard makes it possible for the person to scan a document and send it as a fax directly without saving it. On Windows XP it is a must to save the scanned document first then print it to fax. I want some way to scan and send the documents on the fly, without the extra steps of saving and printing. How is that possible in Windows XP? And if not, is there any third party applications to do that?

**EDIT:** I use hp scanjet 5590...

**EDIT:** Good answers. Actually that was easy enough after installing HP Solution Center and HP Photosmart Essentials. HP Solution Center has a direct option to scan to fax after installing the fax modem driver. @harrymc put good effort in [his answer](https://superuser.com/a/435730/88211) and referred to the obvious solution of installing the software that came along with the scanner. I'm actually done with the driver out of the CD and never installed a scanner or printer software before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most printers/scanners come bundled with print-software that has a "Scan to E-mail" function.

I don't know your printer's model, so I cannot tell if such a function is available.

[EDIT]

The [manual](http://www.math.wisc.edu/computing/other/HP-ScanJet-5590-Scanner-Manual.pdf) of the HP Scanjet 5590 describes the Email button  :

> **e-mail a scanned document or picture**
>
> Use the E-MAIL button to scan documents or pictures and insert them in
>   an  e-mail message as an attachment. You must have an Internet
>   connection and a  supported e-mail software program.
>
> 1. Place the original face-down on the scanner glass, as indicated by
>      the  reference marks, or face-up in the ADF.
> 2. Press the **E-MAIL** button ( [image: button image] ). The **What are you scanning?** dialog box
>      appears.
> 3. Choose the appropriate settings, and then click **Scan**.
> 4. When you are finished scanning, click **Done**. Your e-mail program
>      opens  and the scanned file is attached to an e-mail message.
> 5. The **E-mail attachment** dialog box appears. Type a file name, and then
>      select a file type. Click **Continue**. Follow the on-screen
>      instructions.
> 6. Use your e-mail program to complete and send the e-mail.
>    **Note:** To view the scanned image before you e-mail it, double-click the 
>      attachment in your e-mail software.
>
> To change the e-mail program, open the HP Director, and then select
>   **E-mail Settings** in the **Settings** drop-down list. The **Email Settings**
>   dialog box appears.  Select the e-mail program that you want to use,
>   and then click **OK**.

The HP Director was supposedly bundled with the driver software that you may have installed. If for some reason you do not have this software, you may find it in
[HP Support](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Home.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15179&prodSeriesId=377689&task=&lang=en&cc=us).

[EDIT2]

Sending a fax is also possible with HP Director : see [Sending a Fax from an HP Scanjet Scanner](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=uk&docname=c00032036).

Comment: No, I have no printer. And the scanner is HP Scanjet 5590. Nothing in the software points to 'Scan to Email' feature...

Comment: The button is on the front of the scanner, have you tried pressing it?

Comment: @amyassin - You should keep looking because the button exists.  Otherwise just upgrade the operating system to Windows 7.

Comment: I found the scan to email button, but what I need is a way to send the document as a fax not an email :s

Comment: This is also possible with HP Director : see [Sending a Fax from an HP Scanjet Scanner](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=uk&docname=c00032036).

Comment: You owned the bounty. Thank you. You're a 89.2K, how can you take reps from a poor guy like me :'(

Comment: Hey, I already voted up your question, you poor guy! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the devices and the application. Most manufacturers support "Send to..." functionality straight on the Scanning/All-in-One devices themselves, or at least with bundled/downloadable software. HP provides "HP Image Zone" which should provide the functionality you need.

Nevertheless, what you need should be possible with a TWAIN-compatible application, which [your scanner](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=377691&prodTypeId=15179&prodSeriesId=377689&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=228) and Windows XP's "Scan and Fax" support.

Comment: Actually I've been reading and researching a lot about TWAIN because of your answer. +1 indeed...

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use some 3rd party faxing software (like [Winfax](http://www.winfax.com)) which usually works as a standalone, yet many others (ie Winfax) will install a 'virtual' printer you can 'print' a document to - it will then display the associated program enabling you to send the fax without saving the document...

Comment: Actually Winfax page is offering an alternative which is some kind of a fax server. +1 for I didn't know about fax server...